# Shock from mobile generator

Tags: generator

I was given a mobile generator but it gives an electric shock from the casing when running. Why? How can I check with an MM? How can I stop it happening without the need for an earth spike.

Comment: Read the manual. Earth rod is a requirement.

Comment: Where are you on this planet? Is this generator being used as a standalone portable power source, or to power a building?

Comment: Put the multimeter exactly where you put your hands/feet when you got shocked.  Is this telling you anything you don't already know?  You haven't given us nearly enough information to answer your question, not least, we need to know if this is a house or a vehicle and what the wiring is like that you are feeding, and what appliances are involved.

Comment: A shock from a generator is a bad thing their has to be a fault in the generator to energize the frame , if powering a house their would still need to be a fault someplace to energize the frame if not properly connected. We definitely need more info. And the brand + model of the unit.